# Best way to add new package to ROS that was installed from source (rosinstall_generator)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, raspberrypi, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all,

I have built ROS kinetic from source on my pi using the instructions http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

What is the best way for me to install an additional package without needing to recompile the entire workspace? The last section in the installation guide describes how to add additional packages, however that just adds them to the workspace and then catkin make will rebuild everything.

The [rosinstall_generator page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator) makes it clear how I can generate a rosinstall file for packages not in the current environment (I guess this is what I want?) however this just adds them to the workspace and again, catkin make rebuilds everything.

So is there a way to get catkin_make_isolated to just build and install new packages? Or should I be creating a new workspace and use the --exclude RPP to get the new packages I want to install? The latter sounds messy, I would rather just have one workspace with my entire build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259344/best-way-to-add-new-package-to-ros-that-was-installed-from-source-(rosinstall_generator)/) by [HeZlah](https://answers.ros.org/users/26687/hezlah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make_isolated` is invoked on the entire workspace, but it only rebuilds the things that are new or changed, so adding new packages and recompiling the workspace should be reasonably quick.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HeZlah](https://answers.ros.org/users/26687/hezlah/) on 2017-04-15**:
Weird, I don't know why it always rebuilds everything then..So I should be able to : rosinstall_generator newpackage --deps --exclude RPP | wstool merge -t src - then wstool update -t src

**Comment by [HeZlah](https://answers.ros.org/users/26687/hezlah/) on 2017-04-15**:
And then sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space,  and it should build and install only newpackage?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-15**:
It will re-run cmake for the workspace to rebuild the dependency graph, and then only rebuild the packages that are new or changed.